# foreach array para insertar 4 valores en la misma consulta

Tags: php, mysql, array, pdo

Tengo 4 arrays que vienen por POST de una consulta AJAX y quiero insertar los values de esos 4 array al mismo tiempo en una sola consulta, he logrado combinar 2 arrays y obtener los valores para insertarlos en la BD, pero no se como hacerlo para realizar al mismo el INSERT de los valores de los 4 arrays.

```
   foreach ($data1 as $item) {
          foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
              $products[].= $value;
          }

      }

    foreach ($data2 as $cant) {
          foreach ($cant as $key => $value) {
              $cants[].= $value;
          }

      }

    foreach ($data3 as $price) {
          foreach ($price as $key => $value) {
              $prices[].= $value;
          }

      }

     foreach ($data4 as $amount) {
          foreach ($amount as $key => $value) {
              $amounts[].= $value;
          }

      }
  $sql = "INSERT INTO POS_ordersItems (`To_id`,`order_items`, 
  `order_qty`, `itemPrice`, `invoice_number`, `amount`, `from_id`) 
  VALUES (:toid, :items, :qty, :itemPrice, :invoice, :amount, 
  :from_id)";
  // prepare a stamemnt only once
  $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->bindParam(':toid', $toid);
  $stmt->bindParam(':items', $item);
  $stmt->bindParam(':qty', $cant);
  $stmt->bindParam(':itemPrice', $price);
  $stmt->bindParam(':invoice', $invoice);
  $stmt->bindParam(':amount', $amount);
  $stmt->bindParam(':from_id', $uid);
  $combo = array_combine($products, $cants, $prices, $amounts);
  foreach (array_combine($products, $cants) as $item => $cant) {
  $stmt->execute();
   }
```

Tengo preparada una variable $combo con los arrays, ya probe de esa forma pero tampoco logré sacar los valores en una sola consulta, estaba pensando y leyendo sobre array_merge pero no se si la opción correcta.

La idea es insertar multimples veces el número de productos, con sus cantidades, precios e importes uno por uno

Answer (score 0):

El método `array_combine()` sólo puede recibir dos parámetros. 
Si hacés un `print_r($combo)` vas a recibir este mensaje: 
**Warning:** array_combine() expects exactly 2 parameters, 4 given in x on line y.

Comment: Muchas gracias N.N entonces debería ser con array_merge()?

Comment: Acabo de hacer pruebas con Merge y me acomoda un array tras otro, cómo podría hacer un combine pero de los 4 arrays?

Comment: Creo que en vez de enviarle arreglos distintos para cada tipo de dato, sería mejor enviar un arreglo para cada producto `productos[] = ["toid" => 33, "items" => 42, etc]`, después sería cuestión de recorrerlo, asignarle el valor a las variables e ir llamando a `execute()`

Comment: Voy a intentarlo y comento